# I can't replace some cells of excel with ado.net and update

Tags: c#, excel, ado.net

I can't replace some cells of excel with `ado.net` and `update`.

In some cells I have this string : `='C:\#Control\#RESULT\CUENTAS 2008\` and I want to change this string for `='T:\#Control\#RESULT\CUENTAS 2008\`, but I can't.

This is my code, but I don't know what is the problem?

Anybody can help me please ?

```
namespace Leer_Excel
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void Modificar_Excel(string excelFileName, string sheetName)
        {
            string TextoBuscado = "'C:'";
            string TextoDeRemplazo = "'T:'";

            OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection();

            try
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

                string strConnnectionOle = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFileName + @";Extended Properties=" + '"' + "Excel 12.0;HDR=NO" + '"';
                Connection.ConnectionString = strConnnectionOle;
                Connection.Open();

                string MyCommandText = "UPDATE [" + sheetName + "$B9:B9] SET F1 = REPLACE(F1," + TextoBuscado + "," + TextoDeRemplazo + ") WHERE F1 LIKE '%C:%'";

                Console.WriteLine(MyCommandText);

                cmd.CommandText = MyCommandText;
                cmd.Connection = Connection;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { Console.WriteLine("El fichero {0} no ha podido realizar los updates correctamente {1}", excelFileName,ex.ToString()); }
            finally
            { Connection.Close(); }

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact error message of the exception?

Comment: I don't have any error of the exception. My program work correct, but when I look my excel file, i don't have any change

Comment: Hi, I read for Internet, that I can't change Excel formulas (beginning with "="). I think, this is my problem.

Comment: How I can do this instead ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use another aproach? I have used [EPPlus](https://epplus.codeplex.com/)
You can [download the package from Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/)

This example is working for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication4 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            const string buscado = "C:";
            const string reemplazo = "T:";
            const string test = "='" + buscado;
            using (ExcelPackage xls = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"E:\Libro1.xlsx"))) {
                ExcelWorksheet sheet = xls.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                int row = 1;
                while (sheet.Cells[row, 1].Value != null) {
                    if (sheet.Cells[row, 1].Text.Substring(0, 4) == test) {
                        sheet.Cells[row, 3].Value = sheet.Cells[row, 1].Value.ToString().Replace(buscado, reemplazo);
                    }
                    row++;
                }
                xls.Save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```